# Automatic Downloads in Music app keeps turned off

Tags: macos, itunes, icloud, music

I'm using macOS Catalina, and I've got some troubles with the new Music app. I just clean installed macOS then I tried to download whole my iCloud Music Library to my mac. But 'Automatic Downloads' checkbox keeps turned off when I close the preferences window with OK button. I experienced this issue before I clean install the macOS but it happens even after I clean install the macOS.

I'm using iCloud Music Library. Music list is showing in the app but download looks not enabled. Nothing is being downloaded now. How do I solve it?

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue on macOS Monterey 12.0.1, have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @zh. Unfortunately not.. I gave up on solving the problem